# Financial benefits of installing EV charger for landlords and employers

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, benefits, electricity

This question is based on the location: Vermont, USA. A lot of information regarding federal tax benefits are available online for Electric or Hybrid car owners. However, I am interested to know if there are any such benefits for people investing on installation of EV chargers. I am planning to get a Plug In Hybrid within 4 months. However, I have no charge point either at my apartment or at work. I would like to request my landlord and the parking lot owner at my work to install EV charge points. What economic benefits can I point out based on my state and country?

Answer (score 2):

The public EV chargers can sell electricity at a profit over what they buy the electricity for. And accelerated depreciation is available in the new tax laws for the cost of the equipment.

But the desperate reason for the public city EV chargers is so that plug-in hybrid vehicles can operate in a short all-electric mode. But a hybrid vehicle operating in a short all-electric mode is not really a very good vehicle because it is also operating in a reduced-performance mode. A better operation for a plug-in hybrid is to use the hybrid system to reduce the load on the internal combustion engine but have a fully performing vehicle.

And so that explanation of a plug-in hybrid is why most EV development is going-on to all-electric vehicles. The all-electric vehicle can charge at home and have enough range to get back home from a city commute or from city shopping.

However, as all-electric vehicles reach for more and more range they are becoming too heavy. The BWM i3 which mitigates vehicle weight with a carbon-fiber body and which limits battery weight to a reasonable commute range, that car is really the best battery-powered electric-vehicle.

The next issue is that hydrogen-fuel-cell electric-vehicles can have either less weight or greater driving range than battery-powered electric-vehicles.

I know this is a lot of tough talk but early adopters of electric-vehicles are taking a lot of risk.

In fact premium rear-wheel-drive sedans and coupes are available with 2.0 turbocharged engines and no hybrid system which would increase both weight and cost. These cars are available from Alfa Romeo, BMW, Cadillac, Genesis, Infiniti, Jaguar, Lexus, MB, and others.The car with the small turbocharged internal-combustion engine might be the best choice for many people. For instance the electric-power-grid is not carbon-neutral and therefor the advantage of the electric-vehicle is limited.